# Value not equal to nil crashes program with "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: swift, swift3, nsview

I am trying to set the background color for an NSView using this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var DrawingView: NSView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DrawingView.wantsLayer = true
}
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    DrawingView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.white.cgColor//crashes here
}
```

The `@IBOutlet` is connected, but whenever I call DrawingView.layer, the program crashes with:

```
"unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an optional value"
```

even in a print statement. If I use the console to print `DrawingView.layer`, it comes back with.

```
(CALayer?) $R2 = 0x0000608000049930 {
  ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
}
```

so we should know that the layer is not nil, and yet the error happens when I resume the program

I also tried using `ViewWillAppear()` instead of `awakeFromNib()`, but the result is the same both ways.

I swear I have done this a thousand times without any issues, but is there anything that could cause this strange error?

stack trace:

```
0    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001002f3cc0 swift_reportError + 132
1    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000100311070 _swift_stdlib_reportFatalError + 61
2    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001001070a0 specialized specialized StaticString.withUTF8Buffer<A> ((UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) -> A) -> A + 355
3    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x0000000100283210 partial apply for (_fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never).(closure #2) + 109
4    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001001070a0 specialized specialized StaticString.withUTF8Buffer<A> ((UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) -> A) -> A + 355
5    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x000000010023b3d0 specialized _fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never + 96
6    ReeperG levelmaker                 0x0000000100001e00 ViewController.awakeFromNib() -> () + 177
7    ReeperG levelmaker                 0x0000000100002050 @objc ViewController.awakeFromNib() -> () + 34
8    CoreFoundation                     0x00007fffcc7012e0 -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 217
9    AppKit                             0x00007fffca353771 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1442
10   AppKit                             0x00007fffca45bd46 -[NSNib _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:options:] + 696
11   AppKit                             0x00007fffca45bba3 -[NSNib _instantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 143
12   AppKit                             0x00007fffcab1069b -[NSStoryboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:] + 234
13   AppKit                             0x00007fffca812d46 -[NSStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 70
14   AppKit                             0x00007fffca3cbaf3 -[NSViewController _loadViewIfRequired] + 300
15   AppKit                             0x00007fffca3cba8b -[NSViewController view] + 30
16   AppKit                             0x00007fffca563760 -[NSWindow _contentViewControllerChanged] + 109
17   Foundation                         0x00007fffce129bb8 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 329
18   AppKit                             0x00007fffca5ab2a0 -[NSWindow setValue:forKey:] + 112
19   AppKit                             0x00007fffca5aafb6 -[NSIBUserDefinedRuntimeAttributesConnector establishConnection] + 694
20   AppKit                             0x00007fffca353771 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1284
21   AppKit                             0x00007fffca45bd46 -[NSNib _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:options:] + 696
22   AppKit                             0x00007fffca45bba3 -[NSNib _instantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 143
23   AppKit                             0x00007fffcab1069b -[NSStoryboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:] + 234
24   AppKit                             0x00007fffca344cd8 NSApplicationMain + 780
25   ReeperG levelmaker                 0x0000000100003860 main + 84
26   libdyld.dylib                      0x00007fffe17c9254 start + 1
```

The name of the program is ReeperG levelmaker

Comment: right click the view and make sure there is only one connection

Comment: I checked on the view and the viewController, yes there is only one connection.

Comment: What does the stack trace show for the crash?

Comment: Does the error only happen on resume, not on initial launch?

Comment: This happens on initial launch

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you don't also have a class named DrawingView, and second, never again name a property starting with a capital letter.

Comment: I do not have a class named DrawingView, and why should I not start a property with a capital letter?

Comment: Because it's against convention and the official guidelines: https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/